# sql query group by data of certain range in continuous date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to Write a sql to query group by data within a certain range in continuous date.I'm usig T-SQL.

Table:

```
Date     |  MeterNo|   Data  |
---------|---------|---------|
01-06-15 |  12345  |      10 |
02-06-15 |  12345  |      12 |
03-06-15 |  12345  |      51 |
04-06-15 |  12345  |      56 |
05-06-15 |  12345  |      16 |  
06-06-15 |  12345  |      15 |
07-06-15 |  12345  |      9  |
08-06-15 |  12345  |      53 |
09-06-15 |  12345  |      55 |
10-06-15 |  12345  |      62 |
11-06-15 |  12345  |      8  |
12-06-15 |  12345  |      18 |
```

I would like to have group by result such as follow:

```
|MeterNo| GroupName| StartDate |  EndDate |
|-------|----------|-----------|--------- |
| 12345 |  0(<50)  |  01-06-15 |  02-06-15| 
| 12345 |  1(>=50) |  03-06-15 |  04-06-15| 
| 12345 |  0(<50)  |  05-06-15 |  07-06-15| 
| 12345 |  1(>=50) |  08-06-15 |  10-06-15| 
| 12345 |  0(<50)  |  11-06-15 |  12-06-15|
```

I need to group Data to be less than 50 and larger than 50 in continuous date as below. 
How can I get SQL query to get the result like second result table? thanks in advance!

Comment: please post your attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically gaps and islands problem and you can group the date ranges together by using row number and checking that against the distance for each date from a fixed date, for example date 0 (=1.1.1900). So you can get the result by this:

```
select
  MeterNo,
  Grp,
  min(Date) as StartDate,
  max(Date) as EndDate
from (
  select
    MeterNo,
    Date,
    Grp,
    datediff(day, 0, Date) - RN as DateGroup
  from (
    select
      Date,
      MeterNo,
      case when Data >= 50 then 1 else 0 end as Grp,
      row_number() over (partition by MeterNo, 
          case when Data >= 50 then 1 else 0 end order by date asc) as RN
    from
      table1
    ) X
  ) Y
group by
  MeterNo,
  Grp,
  DateGroup
Order by
  MeterNo,
  StartDate
```

You can test this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d1be/1)

Comment: many thanks.off course, your solution works totally . but it allows to choose just one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternative solution:

```
declare @t table([Date] date, [MeterNo] int, [Data] int);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    ('2015-06-01', 12345, 10),
    ('2015-06-02', 12345, 12),
    ('2015-06-03', 12345, 51),
    ('2015-06-04', 12345, 56),
    ('2015-06-05', 12345, 16),
    ('2015-06-06', 12345, 15),
    ('2015-06-07', 12345, 9),
    ('2015-06-08', 12345, 53),
    ('2015-06-09', 12345, 55),
    ('2015-06-10', 12345, 62),
    ('2015-06-11', 12345, 8),
    ('2015-06-12', 12345, 18);

with cte as(select *,
                   case when data < 50 then 0 else 1 end gr1,
                   ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by MeterNo order by date)-
                   ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by MeterNo, 
                                                  case when data < 50 then 0 else 1 end 
                                     order by date) gr2
           from @t)
select MeterNo, 
       MIN(date) StartDate, 
       MAX(date) EndDate,
       case when gr1 = 0 then '0(<50)' else '1(>=50)' end as GroupName
from cte
group by MeterNo, gr1, gr2
order by StartDate
```

Comment: @stkflmb12 This approach has one possible flaw. If dates can be completely missing from the table, this doesn't notice that at all.

Comment: @JamesZ Could you give an example for the possible flaw?

Comment: @stkflmb12 Leave out date 2015-06-09 from the table, and it still shows range 8 - 10

Comment: @JamesZ  Your approach is more rigorous .Actually,the [Date] column is precise to millisecond such as   2015-06-12 00:02:39.599 ，so it is not continuous time any way,and the flaw would happen when it may lack some data in a time range.so it's complicated in real circumstances,I'll try to fix it based on your answer.

Comment: @stkflmb12 If you don't want to track missing dates, just the start and end date time of certain values, then this will provide better result, since it doesn't care about the actual values, just the order of them

Comment: @JamesZ I have tested your sql query . If you change the ' datediff(day, 0, Date)'  the parameter 'day' to 'second' ,it does't work ,please try to change data of the date column to millisecond and test the sql query.because the time is precise to millisecond in the real developing circumstances,it needs to do so.

Comment: @stkflmb12 Yes of course since that would mean each and every data in the same group would have to be 1 second apart -- it's built for your example data in the question that has 1 row per day.

Comment: @JamesZ   so do you have any other alternative solution if the data of the Date column is precise to millisecond ?